# Cannot connect to another machine via ssh

Tags: ssh

I was able to connect to my xubuntu system installed in a virtual box via ssh from my PC (running Ubuntu 16.04):

```
ssh vtm@192.168.8.103
```

Later, in the same machine (xubuntu) I executed the following commands to enable FTP access:

```
sudo ufw disable
sudo iptables -F
```

Now I cannot connect to it via ssh, I get the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.8.103 port 22: Connection timed out
```

How can  I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that ssh was not allowed by the firewall, so :

`sudo ufw allow ssh`

solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please restart your computer to undo this iptables -F?

If you want to allow FTP why not running:
ufw allow 21/tcp
ufw enable

next please install nmap and check if the port is reachable at all:
apt-get install nmap

then:
nmap -p 22 192.168.8.103
and
nmap -p 21 192.168.8.103

Post the results, I am curious if the ports are reachable at all.